# Merged git branches that should be equal have lots of differences actually

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff

I have inherited a project from a previous developer at my company. There's a master branch and a, say, foo branch. Gitk shows the last commit was a merge of foo into master, so they should be equal. In fact, if I try to do such a merge again by executing:

```
git merge foo
```

on the master branch, it will say that master is "Already up-to-date" as one could expect.

Nonetheless, if I do a diff between them, like:

```
git diff foo
```

from master, I got dozens of changes in dozens of files. And, in fact, if I checkout one branch or another, they are different.

So... why I've got this seemly messing situation? how could I resolve it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing to resolve.  You have merged `foo` into `master`, and Git is aware of this.  That there is a difference between the two does not mean that the merge did not work.

Comment: Shall some moderator with enough rights delete this. I just realized what happened: the other guy didn't merged anything, he executed a merge and solved of conflicts by accepting the master side, whereas he should have done exactly the opposite.

I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: But your question is still generally valid, so no need to delete anything I think.

Comment: Maybe you are right.

Answer (score 2):

`master` got all of `foo` commits, but the reverse is not true, so you could (and obviously do) have differences, namely things in `master` which are *not* in `foo`.

You'd have to merge `master` back into `foo` to make their diff void, although this is rarely needed, at least when it comes to simple feature branches, which are often deleted after they served their purpose.

Answer (score 2):

A Git branch is a pointer to a commit. When you merge two branches (in fact, you merge two commits), a new commit is created and the current branch is moved to the new commit. The merged branch doesn't change.

Here is an example.
The current branch is `A` and there is another branch `B` that diverged from `A` in the past.

```
HEAD -> A -> o    o <- B
             |    |
             o    o
             |   /
             o  o
             | /
             o
             |
```

After `git merge B`, a new commit is created (it has two parents because it is a merge commit) and the branch `A` moves to point to the newly created commit. `B` keeps its previous position.

```
HEAD -> A -> o
             |  \
             o    o <- B
             |    |
             o    o
             |   /
             o  o
             | /
             o
             |
```

After `git merge B`, `git diff B` displays the changes that are in branch `A` but are not present in branch `B`. They are the changes operated on the left branch of the graph, on the commits that are not reachable from the `B` commit.

```
HEAD -> A -> o
             |  \
         /-> o    o <- B
  in A   |   |    |
 but not |-> o    o
  in B   |   |   /
         \-> o  o
             | /
             o
             |
```